# Creating a board game simulator

Tags: python, pygame

I've decided to start working on programming an old favorite of mine. I've never done a game before and also never done a large project in Python.

The game is the old Avalon Hill game [Russian Campaign](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2808)

I've been playing with PyGame a little bit and was wondering if there were reasons not to try to do this with PyGame and go after some other engine/language.

What would be the disadvantages of using Pygame to build this?

I'm not worried about AI, primarily I'd just love to get a minimal two player version of the game up and running. Bonuses would be the ability to save the state of the game and also to play over a network.

Do's and Dont's for starting this project would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Separate the "back-end" engine (which keeps track of board state, receives move orders from front-ends, generates random numbers to resolve battles, sends updates to front-ends, deals with saving and restoring specific games, ...) from "front-end" ones, which basically supply user interfaces for all of this.

PyGame is one suitable technology for a client-side front-end, but you could implement multiple front-ends (maybe a PyGame one, a browser-based one, a text-based one for debugging, etc, etc).  The back-end of course could care less about PyGame or other UI technologies. Python is fine for most front-ends (except ones that need to be in Javascript, Actionscript, etc, if you write front-ends for browsers, Flash, etc;-) and definitely fine for thre back-end.

Run back-end and front-ends as separate processes and communicate as simply as you possibly can -- for a turn-based game (as I believe this one is), XML-RPC or some even simpler variant (JSON payloads going back and forth over HTTP POST and replies to them, say) would seem best.

I'd start with the back-end (probably using JSON for payloads, as I mentioned), as a dirt-simple WSGI server (maybe with a touch of werkzeug or the like to help out with mdidleware), and a simple-as-dirt debugging command-line client.  At each step I would then be enriching either the server side (back-end) or the client side (front-end) carefully avoiding doing too-big OR any simultaneous "steps".  I wouldn't use "heavy" technologies nor any big frameworks doing magical things behind my back (no ORMs, Django, SOAP, ...).

Make sure you use a good source code repository (say hg, or maybe svn if you know you'll be doing it all alone, or bazaar or git if you already know them).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should care about multiple-plateforms support, separation of front-ends and back-ends, multiple processes with communication using XML-RPC and JSON, server, etc.

Drop your bonuses and concentrate on your main idea : a turn-based, two players game. It's your first game so you'll have a lot to learn and taking care of all this at once can be overwhelming.

Comment: The point of separating things out is to make it simpler to actually get working bits done.  Then when it comes time to learn Pygame, the author just has to learn Pygame, as an interface.  Otherwise sprites end up storing game state.  Pygame is hard to debug, a text interface isn't.