# Custom board game, trouble with setting up multiple processes for back/front ends

Tags: python-3.x

I am having issues trying to set up multiple processes for a custom board game I am attempting to program in python3, primarily using the multiprocessing library to split up the front and back ends of my game and then having them communicate via shared memory. (If this it too broad please let me know!)

I am still pretty new to programming, but as a learning experience I am trying to create a complete and custom board game - both the back-end engine (very simplistic board game architecture, think tic-tac-toe-ish) as well as the front-end (which I have started using webGL to create) from scratch.

I have made rough programs for each of these, however my specific issue is communication between the two throughout the 'game time'. I want to use the multiprocessing.array and multiprocessing.value to create variables in shared memory (current board, name, prompts) which I can use in each process to both run the back-end engine and change these variables as well as use in the front-end to display the current board state, name, etc.
which doesn't seem too terribly complex...

BUT I am stuck now trying to have these two programs do a back-and-fourth communication type action as (I believe) they should be doing. This multiprocessing approach seems to run the program to completion. I have used multiprocessing to analyse butt tons of data fairly quickly, but each process simply finished and waited till all of the other ones were done and then joined the data, i.e. all processes were basically the same.

I apologize if this is too broad, but I have not been able to find any resources on this topic, so now I turn to people who have maybe done this before. If anyone could give me any pointers of even what to search, or resources/examples you have come across I would be extremely grateful!

(a friend suggested process signals from one to the other and back, but it seems to simply be another IPC which is why I was originally trying to use shared memory).

Thank you!

Comment: _"to have these two programs do a back-and-fourth communication type action..."_ I bet a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) would be useful here.

Comment: @Kevin : I was originally trying to stay away from piping, but the more I look into it this seems like the way I may have to go! Thanks!

Comment: If anybody else comes across this issue I think I may have found a solution that works for my application - [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157245/creating-a-board-game-simulator-python-pygame) discussion was very useful!